# How to Find basis from set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$P=\{(a+d)x^3+(a+b)x^2+(c+d)x+i(b+c)|a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}\} $$

I need to find basis for this Vector subspace.

my suggest answer :

we got :  $$a(x^3+x^2)+b(x^2+i)+c(x+i)+d(x^3+x)=P$$

so its easy to see that : $$B=\{(1 ,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1),(1,0,1,0)\}$$

is the standard basis .

Is this correct ? if not How Can i find the basis ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B=\{(1 ,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1),(1,0,1,0)\}$

Notice that $$(1 ,1,0,0)-(0,1,0,1)+(0,0,1,1)=(1,0,1,0)$$

Hence the vectors are linearly dependent and cannot be a basis.

Try to prove that $C=\{(1 ,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1)\}$ is linearly independent.

Also note that $(1,1,0,0)$ corresponds to $x^3+x^2$. Try to write out which polynomial those vector correponds to.

Comment: oh that's correct , thanks alot .